# Making multiple asynchronous XMLHTTPRequests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have an array of unknown length (anywhere between 1 and 16), and I'd like to send an XMLHTTPRequest for each item in the array asynchronously. Once the final request is complete, I'd like to print data from each response.

However, currently, only the final item's response is being printed. Does anybody know why this is?

Here is my code:

```
  var responseData = [];
  var numCompletedRequests = 0;

  inputArray.forEach((element) => {

    let newRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    newRequest.open("POST", url, true);

    newRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (newRequest.readyState === 4 && newRequest.status !== 200) {
        // Request failed
        numCompletedRequests++;
        handleFailedRequest(newRequest); // Another function to handle errors

      } else if (newRequest.readyState === 4 && newRequest.status === 200) {
        // Request succeeded
        numCompletedRequests++;
        responseData.push(newRequest.response);
      }

      if (numCompletedRequests === inputArray.length) {
        // This is the last request to come in. Ready to print
        console.log(responseData);
        return;
      }

    newRequest.send(element);
  });
```

For example, if my input array had 3 elements, the output array `responseData` would be 3 elements long, but would contain 3 identical elements: the response of whichever request finished last.

Does anybody know why this is, and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? `responseData.push(newRequest.response));` has a syntax error.

Comment: Did you verify in the devtools network panel that the requests actually do have different responses?

Comment: @Bergi It's a very reduced version and you're right, i'll update it. Thanks! And yes, I've made the backend that its pinging and can see its returning different responses.

Answer (score 0):

What about use Promise.All ?

```js
const url1 = "url1"
const url2 = "url2"
const url3 = "url3"

const fetchMultiAsync = async () => {
    const responses = await Prmoise.all([fetch(url1),fetch(url2),fetch(url3)])
    return responses
}

fetchMultiAsync() // return [response of req1, req2, req3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, to get responses for XMLHTTPRequests I believe you need to use their onreadystateexchange function, so Promise.all doesn't work.

Comment: @stripedapus `Promise.all()` works fine here.  This example uses the Fetch API instead, which is a good modern replacement for most any XHR usage.  But, even if you wanted to use XHR, you could wrap your XHR call in a promise and use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: @stripedapus newRequest.open("POST", url, true);

URL should vary depending on your element of inputArray. Is it sure?

Comment: @Brad thanks for the help, but still no avail. I tried wrapping my XHR into a promise but the same thing kept happening. Weirdly enough, when I step through with the debugger it works as intended - strange